# Modal closing when I click on anywhere except the selected region

Tags: javascript

I made three boxes each have their own buttons, onclick of them their respective modals will pop out, and they will get close when I click anywhere else, which you can see by the link which I have shared below. Now the  issue arising is that, when I click on the modal itself(on the modal), its getting closed, which is wrong. I'm trying to solve this but not getting any sufficient solution, might get help from you guys.

[enter link description here](http://modal.imarkclients.com/)

Snippet:

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(".btnOne").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalOne").addClass("open");
        $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
    });
    $(".btnTwo").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalTwo").addClass("open");
        $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
    });
    $(".btnThree").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalThree").addClass("open");
        $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
    });
  
    //Keep an eye on this part 
    $('html').click(function () {
        $(".modal").removeClass("open");
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #eee;
}
.btn {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #f00;
}
.modal {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal.open {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnOne">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalOne">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnTwo">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalTwo">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnThree">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalThree">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".btnOne").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".modalOne").addClass("open");
  $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
  $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
});
$(".btnTwo").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".modalTwo").addClass("open");
  $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
  $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
});
$(".btnThree").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(".modalThree").addClass("open");
  $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
  $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
});
$(document).on("click touchstart", function(e) {
  var container = $(".modal");
  console.log()
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass("open") && !$(e.target).closest(".modal").hasClass("open") ) {
    container.removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 1170px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #eee;
}
.btn {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #f00;
}
.modal {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal.open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <button type="button" class="btn btnOne">button</button>
    <div class="modal modalOne">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button type="button" class="btn btnTwo">button</button>
    <div class="modal modalTwo">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has</p>
      <h1>asas</h1>
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <button type="button" class="btn btnThree">button</button>
    <div class="modal modalThree">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check snippet code

Comment: In this case, if the modal is open on div 1, and if we click inside div 2, then the modal on div 1 wont close.

Comment: Now please add some elements inside the modal(say h1 , p and etc) and then try the same, and then try clicking inside the modal, it will get close. That's the main issue that m facing.

Comment: @VinayPatial if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark :)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to check on `.modal.open`

```
$('html').click(function(evt) {
  if (!$(evt.target).closest(".modal").is(".modal.open")) {
    $(".modal.open").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

Check out this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ecpx3pg/

Comment: Hey, I used this and its working for me, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Please check the shared link again, now when I'm adding some content inside the modal and click on the modal inside its getting closed, strange.

Comment: You can use `!$(evt.target).closest(".modal").is(".modal.open")` as the condition for the `if()`. (I added a jsfiddle link the my answer)

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is [`event.target`](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) from jQuery. You'll always get the whole "html" node if you listen to the click event on it. However, you are able to gain the node which were directly clicked by the `eve.target` object.

Example:

```js
$( "body" ).click(function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).html( "clicked: " + event.target.nodeName );
});
```

```css
  span, strong, p {
    padding: 8px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<div>
  <p>
    <strong><span>click</span></strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

The usage in your case is:

```
$('html').click(function (eve) {
  if(!eve.target.className.contains("open")){
    $(".modal").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

Node that I've added an if which checks whether the clicked target is an open modal (className.contains.("open")).

Here's the full code:

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(".btnOne").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalOne").addClass("open");
        $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
    });
    $(".btnTwo").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalTwo").addClass("open");
        $(".modalThree").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
    });
    $(".btnThree").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".modalThree").addClass("open");
        $(".modalOne").removeClass("open");
        $(".modalTwo").removeClass("open");
    });
  
    //Keep an eye on this part 
    $('html').click(function (eve) {
      if(!eve.target.className.contains("open")){
        $(".modal").removeClass("open");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #eee;
}
.btn {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #f00;
}
.modal {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal.open {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnOne">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalOne">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnTwo">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalTwo">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <button type="button" class="btn btnThree">button</button>
            <div class="modal modalThree">
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Another hint. You kind of misuse the class attribute. You may want to add "modalOne", "modalTwo" and "modalThree" as ids.

For example:

```
    <div class="modal" id="2">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and 
    </div>
```

You avoid duplicated information doing so and you avoid having trouble with CSS styles priorities.

Further reading:

- https://api.jquery.com/event.target/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className
- Important: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes